# C3.js code hosted in MVC.NET razor rendered view does not display a graph

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c3.js

I am trying to get the C3.js code below:

```
<link href="well.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href=@Url.Content("c3.css") rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src=@Url.Content("d3.js") charset="utf-8"> </script>
<script src=@Url.Content("c3.js")> </script>

@* Chart holder for C3JS display *@
<div> <span id="chart"></span></div>

<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
            ]
        }
    });
</script>
```

to display in a Razor rendered view under MVC.NET.

Have you any ideas why it does not display a graph anything?

Thanks and cheers

Mike

Comment: Are the paths to the css and js files correct? should the creation be in `document ready` to be sure `#chart` exists? Any errors in the Output window?

Comment: check firebug if you are getting an error

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  It turns out that it was an unknown white space character.  I deleted the offending line and retyped it.